# How to handle correctly a big amount of objects in node/socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So, I have a game map of 10000x10000. I want to have lets say 10000 random objects placed on the map so that every player that's connected to the server will be able to access them. When the selected amount of objects is a big number, the server can't take it anymore. This is what I currently have in my `server.js`

```
class gmObject {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

var objs = [];

for(var i=0; i<10000; i++){
    objs.push(new gmObject(Math.random()*10000, Math.random()*10000));
}

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('spawnObjects', JSON.stringify(objs));
});
```

and my `client.js`

```
var objs = [];

socket.on('spawnObjects', function(data) { objs = JSON.parse(data); }
```

This will do the job, but the continuous annoying lag will still be there. How can I do this properly and improve the performance of my game? thanks in advance

Comment: for example in agar.io there is a ton of foods placed on the map that players can eat

Comment: apparently using custom de/serialization is a way to go